# Can a Typescript array of class objects accept child classes?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this:

```
class Foo{};
class Bar extends Foo {};
class Blah extends Foo {};

const fooArray: Foo[] = [];
```

Can I push Bar and Blah into fooArray and have them retain all their subclass behavior?

Comment: Yes you can. The object won't change if that's the question, in fact typescript types are erased at compile time and do not affect values at runtime

Comment: Okay thanks just making sure that's intended.